# Discord.js how to remove all roles from all users?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to remove all roles of all users and add the initial role, but it doesn't remove from all users some I'm getting this error:

```
{
  timeout: 6998,
  limit: 10,
  method: 'patch',
  path: '/guilds/951903386557636729/members/1027401729962168350',
  route: '/guilds/951903386557636729/members/:id',
  global: false
}
```

Here my code:

Removing roles

```js
await interaction.guild.members.cache.forEach(m => {
    m.roles.remove(m.roles.cache)
});
```

Removing nicknames

```js
setTimeout(() => interaction.guild.members.cache.forEach(m => {
    m.setNickname("")
}), 30 * 60000)
```

Add initial role

```js
setTimeout(() => interaction.guild.members.cache.forEach(m => {
    (m.roles.add(entradacargo)) 
}), 31 * 60000)
```

I managed to make it work the Removing Roles and Removing Nicknames. But when go to Add initial roles the bot don't give to all members, someone know how to fix it?

Comment: Can you include the full error

Comment: 99% sure those errors you get are either something to do with permissions and / or rate limits (spam). And ofcourse, that remaining 1% could be anything, but we'll know for sure if you [edit] your question by adding the error logs.

Comment: it was rate limit, can i do something to not receive this error? something to go slowly removing roles?

Comment: The procedure is spammy in nature, why do you need to remove all roles from all members? Have you thought of alternatives

Comment: it's a gta rp fac server, the server gonna wipe then i need to remove the roles. I think to delete the roles, but there's other configurations with the roles id's, so the better way for me it's to remove the roles and put the initial role even if it took 30 minutes long.

Comment: I managed to make it work the Removing Roles and Removing Nicknames, but when go to Add initial roles the bot don't give to all members, someone know how to fix it?

Answer (score -1):

```js
Interaction#guild.members.cache.forEach(member => {
  member.roles.cache.forEach(role => {
    member.roles.remove(role);
  });
});
```

This is the code for removing all roles from all members, however do know it cannot alter the roles that are higher than it's own. And it can also not modify the nickname of the Guild Owner.

Going through the code, you can see that it references the Interaction's Guild, iterates through every member, then iterates through all of the member's cached roles.

Comment: I'm doing this way now and its working

`                let n = 0
                interaction.guild.members.fetch().then(m => {
                    m.forEach(member => {
                        setTimeout(() => {
                            member.roles.remove(member.roles.cache)
                        }, (++n) * 2000);
                    })
                })`
It gonna remove with 2 seconds delay to avoid rate limit